# Debug a script that is in your PATH?

Tags: shell-script

`script` is a shell script that can be found in `PATH` directories.

To run it in debug mode, can I use something simpler than:

```
sh -x $(which script)
```

Comment: If you'd be using `zsh`, you could write `bash -x =script` ;)

Comment: can't you make it in a script that is in your `PATH`?

Comment: @Moonstroke You mean, create a script named `script_debug` that contains `bash -x $(which $1)` and run `script_debug script`? That seems like a nice one actually.

Comment: Why are you running the script in question under `bash` when it is not necessarily a bash script? It is most likely a `sh` script but it could also be a `zsh` script, a `ksh` script, etc...

Comment: @Celada No it is an `sh` script. I will fix the question.